# Почему HttpContext.SignInAsync выдаёт ошибку?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Program

```
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Defult"));
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Cookie").AddCookie("Cookie", options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Register";
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RegisteredUser", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireRole(ClaimTypes.Role, "RegisteredUser");
    });
```

Context

```
public class IdentityContext : DbContext
    {
        public IdentityContext(DbContextOptions options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<RegisteredUser> RegisteredUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModle modle)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(await _Database.RegisteredUsers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Login == modle.Login) is null)
            {
                var user = new RegisteredUser
                {
                    Email = modle.Email,
                    Password = Convert.ToHexString(_PasswordHash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(modle.Password))),
                    Login = modle.Login
                };

                await _Database.AddAsync(user);
                await _Database.SaveChangesAsync();

                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.Email),
                    new(ClaimTypes.Role, "RegisteredUser")
                };

                var claimsId = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Cookie", ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType);
                await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Cookie", new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsId));

                return Redirect(modle.ReturnUrl);
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Такой пользователь уже существует");
        }

        return View(modle);
    }
```

[image: Сама ошибка]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Есть атрибут authorize, и после добавления в базу, пользователь должен заходить на представления помеченные authorize, в место этого вылетает исключения

Answer (score 0):

1. Пакет NuGet для работы с аутентификацией и авторизацией стоит?
2. Установлен пакет Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication?
3. Если всё стоит, то настроен-ли сервис аутентификации в ConfigureServices в Startup.cs, и middleware в методе Configure?
4. Добавили сервис аутентификации в IServiceCollection, используя метод AddAuthentication, и настроили middleware используя метод UseAuthentication и  UseAuthorization?
5. Зависимости для работы с аутентификацией и авторизацией, включая Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity и другие.

Пишу много по авторизации потому что код заклинил на await SignInAsync. Могу быть не прав.

6. По ошибкам с XML - по умолчанию HttpContent пытается прочитать контент как XML, а не как JSON или другой тип контента. Возможно необходимо установить правильный заголовок Content-Type в запросе и/или ответе, чтобы указать, какой тип контента отправляется и принимается.

Comment: Я создал новый проект asp .NET MVC с типом проверки пользователей индивидуальные учётные записи и выяснил, что эта ошибка появляется при создании проекта. Если ничего не менять, то сама ошибка вскакивает, когда нажимаешь на Login.